# Energy Monitor using Minimalmodbus and PZEM 016 device

Tags: python-3.x, modbus, raspberry-pi-zero, minimalmodbus, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I am trying to clear the energy counter for a Peacefair AC PZEM 016 energy monitor. I have a nice little script going that measures the values of the registers, however, I can not clear the energy through the minimalmodbus library and keep getting multiple errors when trying code, but the main one I get is "Slave reported Illegal Data Value." The link to the documentation is here https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GtkIOyZaL.pdf. The "Reset Energy" is under section 2.5, but I swear this should not be this hard.

```
import minimalmodbus
import datetime
import time
import serial
import sys
import os
import threading
from crccheck.crc import Crc16

mb_address = 1 
clear_energy_command = 0x42
powark_sensor = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0',mb_address) 

powark_sensor.serial.baudrate = 9600
powark_sensor.serial.bytesize = 8
powark_sensor.serial.parity = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_NONE
powark_sensor.serial.stopbits = 1
powark_sensor.serial.timeout = 0.5
powark_sensor.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU

file_path = "/home/josiahferguson/Documents/powark/mb_powark_data.txt"

powark_sensor.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
powark_sensor.close_port_after_each_call = True

print("")
print("Requesting Data From Powark...")
print("")
#single_data = powark.sensor.read_register(1, 1, 3, False)
#print(f"Single register data = {single_data}")

#function to read powark data
def read_sensor_data():
    data = powark_sensor.read_registers(0, 10, 4)

    volts = data[0] / 10
    ampslow = int(data[1]) / 1000
    ampshigh = int(data[2]) / 1000
    wattslow = int(data[3]) / 10
    wattshigh = int(data[4]) / 10
    watthourslow = int(data[5])
    watthourshigh = int(data[6])
    hertz = int(data[7]) / 10
    powerfactor = int(data[8]) / 100
    alarm = data[9]

    processed_data = {
        "volts": volts,
        "ampslow": ampslow,
        "ampshigh": ampshigh,
        "wattslow": wattslow,
        "wattshigh": wattshigh,
        "watthourslow": watthourslow,
        "watthourshigh": watthourshigh,
        "hertz": hertz,
        "powerfactor": powerfactor,
        "alarm": alarm,
    }

    return processed_data

powark_sensor_data = read_sensor_data()

#function to write sensor data to file
def write_data_to_file(powark_sensor_data, file_path):
    with open (file_path, "a") as file:
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
        file.write(f"{timestamp}: {powark_sensor_data}\n")

def low_byte(value):
    return value & 0xFF

def high_byte(value):
    return (value >> 8) & 0xFF

powark_sensor.write_long(mb_address, 0x42, False, 2)

# ~ powark_sensor.serial.open()
# ~ time.sleep(1)
# ~ # Calculate the CRC-16 using the CRC library
# ~ crc = Crc16.calc(bytearray([mb_address, clear_energy_command]))

# ~ # Send the slave address, reset command, and CRC-16
# ~ powark_sensor.serial.write(bytearray([mb_address, clear_energy_command, low_byte(crc), high_byte(crc)]))

# ~ # Wait for the energy monitor to process the command
# ~ time.sleep(0.26)

# ~ response = powark_sensor.serial.read(4)  # The expected response length is 4 bytes
# Check if the response is correct or an error reply
# ~ if len(response) == 0:
    # ~ print("No Response Received")
    # ~ print("")
# ~ elif response[0] == mb_address and response[1] == clear_energy_command:
    # ~ print("Energy Reset")
    # ~ print("")
# ~ elif response[0] == mb_address and response[1] == 0xC2:
    # ~ print("Error resetting energy. Abnormal code:", response[2])
    # ~ print("")
# ~ else:
    # ~ print("Unexpected response:", response)
    # ~ print("")


#fucntion to clear the energy data from the powark sensor
def clear_energy_used(port, mb_adrress):
    try:
        powark_sensor.write_register(clear_energy_command, 6)
        print("Energy data cleared successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error clearing energy data: {e}")

#function to display sensor values to the console
def print_powark_values():
    print(f"Voltage: {powark_sensor_data['volts']} Volts")
    print("-------------------------")
    print(f"Current: {powark_sensor_data['ampslow']} Amps")
    print("-------------------------")

    #converts Watts to Kilowatts if the value exceeds 999.99
    if powark_sensor_data['wattslow'] >= 1000:
        print(f"Charging Rate: {powark_sensor_data['wattslow']/1000} Kilowatts")
    else:
        print(f"Charging Rate: {powark_sensor_data['wattslow']} Watts")
    print("-------------------------")

    #converts energy (watt hours) to Kilowatts if the value exceeds 999.99
    if powark_sensor_data['watthourslow'] >= 1000:
        print(f"Energy Added: {powark_sensor_data['watthourslow']/1000} Kilowatts")
    else:
        print(f"Energy Added: {powark_sensor_data['watthourslow']} Watts")

    print("-------------------------")
    print(f"Frequency: {powark_sensor_data['hertz']} Hz")
    print("")
    print(f"{powark_sensor_data['powerfactor']} Powerfactor")
    print("")
    print(f"{powark_sensor_data['alarm']}")
    print("")
    
print_powark_values()

print("Writing Data to mb_powark_data.txt File...")
write_data_to_file(powark_sensor_data, file_path)
print("")
print("Now Closing Serial Port")
powark_sensor.serial.close()
print("")

#
#user input handling to start logging data to the file
entered_value = input('Would you like to start a session?: y or n  ')
print("")

if entered_value == 'y':
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Your charging session has started!")
    print("")
    max_iterations = int(input("How many iterations would you like this to run?:  "))
    print("")
    iteration_count = 0

    while iteration_count <= max_iterations:
        # Read sensor data
        powark_sensor_data = read_sensor_data()
        # write_data_to_file(powark_sensor_data, file_path)
        write_data_to_file(powark_sensor_data, file_path)

    #print values to console
        print_powark_values()
        time.sleep(1)
    # Close the serial port
        powark_sensor.serial.close()
        iteration_count += 1
        if iteration_count >= max_iterations:
            print("")
            print("Ports now closed")
            print("")
            #print("Clearing Data")
            #clear_energy_used('/dev/ttyUSB0', mb_address)
            print("Thanks for using Powark!")
            break
    # Wait for the specified delay before the next iteration
else:
    print("Ports now closed")
    print("Thanks for using Powark!")
```

Comment: My reading of the spec is that it's expecting function code `0x42` (as opposed to `0x06` for Write single register). The [Modbus spec](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf) does not include this function code so it's unlikely to be supported by libraries (you will probably need to write your own code to send the command and handle the response).

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual you have to write *nothing* to register `0x42`, I would try something like this:

```
powark_sensor.write_register(clear_energy_command, None, 0, 6, False) # address, value, number of decimals, function code, signed)
```

I am not sure minimal is able to handle writing `None` to a register. And even if it is I think your device is not expecting you to write to register `0x42` but just writing the 4 bytes you see in the manual (I'm getting this from reading [this piece of code](https://github.com/EvertDekker/Pzem016Test/blob/master/Pzem016Test.ino)

With that in mind, I'd suggest you use pyserial to write those 4 raw bytes to the port. To calculate the CRC you can try to use minimal's internal function:

```
minimalmodbus._calculate_crc_string('\x01\x42')
```

And attach those after `\x42`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it! It turns out the correct command to clear energy for a PZEM 016 is ._perform_command(0x42, '').